# How to modify a reactive Array in place?

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, reactive-programming

In pure JS it is possible to modify an Array in place:

```js
a = ["a", "b"]
a.forEach((e, i, a) => {
  a[i] = e + " hello"
})
console.log(a)
```

I tried to port this code to Vue but the modification does not happen:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    a: ["a", "b"]
  },
  mounted() {
    this.a.forEach((e, i, a) => {
      a[i] = e + " hello"
    })
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.13/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  {{ a }}
</div>
```

Is it possible to make such modifications in reactive data in Vue?

Comment: "reactive" and "in place" don't play well together. Make it immutable: `this.a = this.a.map(x => x + hello)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, I mean with the array mutation in place, you should use the `beforeMount` lifecycle hook: since `mounted` is executed after the DOM updates, you do not see the result of your forEach operation.

See the Lifecycle Diagram on the official documentation [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Lifecycle-Diagram).

However, as suggested in a comment above

> "reactive" and "in place" don't play well together.

Make it immutable whenever it is possible. I mean something like:

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    a: ["a", "b"]
  },
  beforeMount() {
    this.a = this.a.map(x => x + " hello")
  }
})
```